# how to implement 3 attempts login form using javascript prompt() method. it ddnt check for the next after 2nd attempt

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3

I want to implement 3 attempts login form using javascript prompt() method. it shows You have left 2 attempt and ddnt check for the next attempt. how to solve this?
  here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var attempt = 3;
    var userName=prompt("Username","");
    var passWord=prompt("Password","");
    if (userName+passWord=="john2541798432" || userName+passWord=="tim3591798752") 
    {
    alert('success');
}       
else
{
attempt --;// Decrementing by one.
alert("You have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
if( attempt == 0)
{
    alert('you are blocked');
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loggedin = false;
var attempt = 3;
while(!loggedin && attempt > 0){
  var userName=prompt("Username","");
  var passWord=prompt("Password","");
  if (userName+passWord=="john2541798432" || userName+passWord=="tim3591798752")
  {
    loggedin = true;
    alert('success');
  }
  else
  {
  attempt --;// Decrementing by one.
  alert("You have left "+attempt+" attempt;");
  if( attempt == 0)
  {
    alert('you are blocked');
  }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your script, I think you can add a hidden input field and update the value of hidden field to verify the maximum attempt. Please see the below script

```
<input type="hidden" id="attempt" value="3">

<script type="text/javascript">

while(1)
{
    var userName=prompt("Username","");

    if(userName != "")
        var passWord=prompt("Password","");

    var attempt = document.getElementById("attempt").value;

    if(userName != "" && passWord != "")
    {
        if (userName+passWord=="john2541798432" || userName+passWord=="tim3591798752") 
        {
            alert('success'); 
            break;
        }       
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("attempt").value = attempt -1;
            alert("You have left "+(attempt-1)+" attempt;");

            attempt = attempt - 1;
            if( attempt == 0)
            {
                alert('you are blocked'); 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: then let me know how attempt value is updated in the textfield

Comment: using input field id, ex: document.getElementById("attempt").value = attempt - 1. where attempt is current value and we are decreasing by 1.

Comment: let me know how to set both field as required

Comment: answer updated with required condition. We just need to check the fields value is empty or not if empty we will show same prompt again.

Comment: when i clicked cancel button, it also considering as attempt and after 3 attempts blocked. how to solve this ie the prompt should close when i clicked cancel button